# xlsx package can't be loaded

Tags: r, windows-7, xlsx

XLSX package is not loading in WIndows 7 with Rstudio 3.5.3

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Comment: RStudio is merely an IDE and plays little to no role in how packages are handled. Have you installed and  configured java (e.g. see [here](https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/))?

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely resolved by installing a Java version (e.g. 64-bit Java or 32-bit Java) that corresponds to the type of R version that you are using (e.g. 64-bit R or 32-bit R).

```
# check which version of R you are running
Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")

# check which version of Java is being utilized by R
system("java -version")
```

If you need a different version of Java then you'll need to manually download and install the right version from [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp). Don't forget to restart R and your browser after you install Java.